# Mocking void methods in Groovy

Tags: groovy, mocking, closures, mockito, dynamic-languages

I ran into a similar bug between Groovy 2.x and Mockito [as this user did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375356/bug-in-mockito-with-grails-groovy), where the `Mockito.doNothing(...)` method throws exceptions in Groovy for no apparent reason.

The accepted answer to that question explains what is happening:

> The problem is Groovy is intercepting your method call before it reaches `someVoidMethod`. The method actually being called is `getMetaClass` which is not a void method.

I'm wondering: is there a "*Groovier*" way to mock void methods? Meaning, is there a way (a Groovy mocking lib, perhaps a technique involving closures or other dynamic constructs, etc.) to mock void methods with Groovy that would circumvent the problem in that identified question.

**Please don't mark this as a dupe:** if you notice, the accepted answer to that question just explained the root problem, but doesn't offer up any alternative, Groovy-friendly solution.

---

#### Example of mocking void method

Below, `EntityValidator` and `WebResource` are from third-party libs. `Address` is a class that is a part of my project.

```
@Test
void test() {
    given:
    EntityValidator mockValidator = Mockito.mock(EntityValidator)
    WebResource mockResource = Mockito.mock(WebResource)
    Address mockAddress = Mockito.mock(Address)
    Mockito.doNothing().when(mockValidator).validateId(1L)
    Mockito.when(mockResource.get(Address)).thenReturn(mockAddress)

    GetAddressCommandImpl fixture = new GetAddressCommandImpl(mockValidator, mockResource)
    fixture.id = 1L

    when:
    Address address = fixture.run()

    then:
    assert(address == mockAddress)
}
```

Comment: Can You provide a scenario for mocking a void method?

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - I would think this would be useful when including 3rd party OSS classes in your tests, and really anytime your main/target method executes another void method that changes state in a way that is not test-friendly. See my update for the problem at hand, but I'm looking for a solution to fit all void methods, not just the one above.

Comment: Does `mockValidator` throw any exception?

Comment: Thanks again @Opal (+1) - but I'm hesitant to answer that because, again, its driving the answer to this question down into something that is specific to that one use case. Whereas I'm interested in a Groovy solution for mocking *any* method that returns void.

Comment: Ok. I hope I'll write an answer later on and a general comment.

Comment: Thanks again @Opal (+1) - I hope so too :-)